How to get a telegram bot to forward messages from a telegram channel
Why is my bot complaining about the ID if it is specified correctly?
import telebot
from telebot import types


bot = telebot.TeleBot ('token')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["rules"])
def rules(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':

  chat = "2112989841"

bot.forward_message('id, 2112989841, 165')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)

I expected that a person would enter a command and the bot would forward the desired messageyour text
Error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Boss\PycharmProjects\ClanwarsHLTVBot\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import rules
  File "C:\Users\Boss\PycharmProjects\ClanwarsHLTVBot\rules.py", line 15, in <module>
    bot.forward_message('id, 2112989841, 165')
TypeError: TeleBot.forward_message() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'from_chat_id' and 'message_id'

Process finished with exit code 1

